# Web Api 2 - How to send attribute from $http call to controller (attribute routing)

Tags: c#, javascript, angularjs, url-routing, asp.net-web-api2

I have this $http call :

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/PhotoSubmit/GetCategories',
        accept: 'application/json'
    })
        .success(function (result) {
            $scope.categories = result;
        });
```

... which needs to send the parameter to this HTTPGET method :

```
[Route("api/PhotoSubmit/GetCategories/{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public object GetCategories(int id)
    {
        return FileServices.GetCategoriesForUser().Select(c => new { Id = c.Id, Name = c.Name });
    }
```

Th routing works, i'm just not sure how to access it by angular/javascript to send it to the controller (OR... how the route-call should look like in the $http call

This is the URL :

```
http://localhost:63203/Index.html#/photosubmit/1
```

Comment: your javascript url doesn't have a base (`localhost:63203`) or a parameter

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure what you mean here.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id can be passed through url itself.

```
url: '/api/PhotoSubmit/GetCategories/1',
```

or you can pass this in params too.

```
$http({
    url: '/api/PhotoSubmit/GetCategories', 
    method: "GET",
    params: {id: 1}
 });
```

Comment: But... One thing... When you type params: id: 1,   how do you get the param from the url or route?

Comment: params send these parametre in request parametre of http call. and controller extracts the values from request parametre on behalf of there name.

Comment: Well.. i'm almost there :) but... this is "unknown territory" for me still.. :) I'm getting 
Object { $id="1", returnData=7}
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://localhost:63203/api/PhotoSubmit/GetCategories/:id?id=1"

... when i injected routeParams and used : var photoId = $routeParams.id;

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure $http is similar, but I'm using $resource in a factory to hit my web api endpoint.

In **services.js**, I have:

```
var app = angular.module('app.service', ['ngResource']);

app.factory('api', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
'use strict';
return {
    Categories: $resource('/api/PhotoSubmit/GetCategories/:id', {id: '@id'})
    };
}]);
```

Then in my controller, I call it with

```
$scope.categories = api.Categories.get({id:"1"});
```

If you really want to start having fun, you can wait and use the data after the results come back using a $promise.

```
api.Categories.get({id:"1"})
    .$promise
    .then(function (results){
        $scope.categories = results;
    });
```

**Update:**
To get the variable into $routeParams, I'm doing the following (bear in mind, this was my first angular app, so there are better ways to code this.)

In my **app.config**, I have the following code to create an id parameter:

```
$routeProvider
    ...
    .when('photosubmit/:id', {
        templateUrl: "photo.html",
        controller: "PhotoController"
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
```

Then, I get the param in the controller `$scope.$routeParams = $routeParams;`

I had to do this at the top so it doesn't get lost or undefined.

Next, you can access the variable you created in the route by using `$scope.$routeParams.id`

Comment: Well.. i'm almost there :) but... this is "unknown territory" for me still.. :) I'm getting 
Object { $id="1", returnData=7}
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://localhost:63203/api/PhotoSubmit/GetCategories/:id?id=1"

... when i injected routeParams and used : var photoId = $routeParams.id;

Comment: so... i still dont understand completely how i can get the parameter when the url is looking like this : 

http://localhost:63203/Index.html#/photosubmit/1

does it "magically" understand that this is "id" ?

Comment: and.. it seems like this is not right due to the "double id" error :
url: '/api/PhotoSubmit/GetCategories/:id',

Comment: If you pass ID:1 as a param it will show up as ?id=1 at the end of your string. This is why I use the variable :id and assign it in the code. As for getting the parameter from the url, when someone goes to photosubmit/1, you're wanting to do an api call to photosubmit/getcategories/1? You'll have to use routing to assign it to a variable. I'll update my answer.